# How do I add multiple conditions to an .htaccess redirect properly?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've got a news aggregation website and currently I am trying to set up Twitter accounts for some of the top cities. In order to automate these bots I am using RSS feeds. To generate RSS feeds that didn't have 100s of posts an hour I had to create another server that scrapes less news. Its a wordpress site so they have rss feeds by default at the end of every slug (Example: fakesite.com/feed or fakesite.com/usa/dallas/feed). I created a redirect that will send people from this smaller server to the larger server by referencing the subdirectory that all posts are under. The problem is that the feed url is also being forwarded to the one I was trying to avoid Tweeting. Is there a way I can add a condition that will tell the server not to redirect if the slug ends in "/feed"?

So far I have this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/us/
RewriteRule (.*) https://urlocal.news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

All of my posts are under the /us/ subdirectory but so are the feeds.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/us/    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed    
RewriteRule (.*) https://urlocal.news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's not doing anything. TBH I have no idea what the syntax I should be using is. I'm on a Bitnami wordpress install and tbh they set it up in a confusing manner. I put this in my `htaccess.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$` to match at the end.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/us/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/feed$
RewriteRule (.*) https://urlocal.news/$1 [R=301,L]
```